# How to fix 'Unclosed element a' in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running a Onlineshop with Woocommerce and got a missing `</a>` in the product rating part.

```
$account_page_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
if ( $account_page_url ) {
/* translators: %s opening and closing link tags respectively */
$comment_form['must_log_in'] = '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'You must be %slogged in%S to post a review.', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . esc_url( $account_page_url ) . '">', '</a>' ) . '</p>';
}
```

Even though the closing tag is included in the PHP file it is still missing on the product page.

Comment: Your second %s is capitalized... I think it needs to be lower case

Comment: To clarify, I think the string should be this: `You must be %slogged in%s to post a review.`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, you were right the capitalized %s caused the error and is gone now.